# Show window figure with two sub figures, an image and its histogram

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to both an image and its histogram in a window figure. I tried:

```
img  = imread('pout.tif');
hist = histogram(img);
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(img)
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(hist)
```

But with this I'm getting the histogram in another window.

What's the supposed way to acomplish that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html), it's shown that you can optionally provide the axes for the `histogram` function, so this should work

```
img = imread('pout.tif');
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(img)
sp2 = subplot(1,2,2)
histogram(sp2, img);
```

If you want to store the `histogram` output then use

```
h = histogram(sp2, img);
```

However, avoid using `hist` as a variable name, because it is the name of an in-built Matlab function.

Comment: I would like code like this... img_histogram = histogram(img);
imshow(img_histogram); Is that some way to block matlab histogram from showing the figure imediatly?